# Writing a simple "process of elimination" Prolog code using DCGs

Tags: prolog, dcg, zebra-puzzle

I have simplified a more complex problem to the following: there are three houses on a street with three different colours (no colour repeated); red, blue, green. Write a program using DCGs to simulate all permutations/possibilities. My code won't run and I'm struggling to see why. Any corrections would really help.

```
s --> h(X), h(Y), h(Z), X\=Y, X\=Z, Y\=Z.

h(X) --> Col(X).

Col(X) --> [red].
Col(X) --> [blue].
Col(X) --> [green].
```

Answer (score 2):

`s/Col/col/`

And then, you are using within `s//0` Prolog goals in the place of non-terminals. That does not work, you need to "escape" them with `{}//0` like so

```
s -->h(X),h(Y),h(Z),{X\=Y,X\=Z,Y\=Z}.
```

But I would rather write:

```
s --> {dif(X,Y), dif(Y,Z), dif(X,Z)}, h(X),h(Y),h(Z).
```

In this manner Prolog performs all the bookkeeping for you.

If we're at it. Don't forget to call the non-terminal via `phrase/2`. Thus:

```
?- phrase(s, L).
```

Comment: I added the curly brackets, but the code produces the same error.

Comment: Do you see `s/Col/col/` at the beginning of my answer? That means substitute `Col` by `col`.

Answer (score 2):

You are (also) forgetting to 'return' the value from the leaves:

```
...
col(red)-->[red].
...
```

With a so small dataset, it's tempting to hardcode the permutation:

```
s --> r,g,b ; r,b,g ; g,r,b ; b,r,g ; g,b,r ; b,g,r.
r --> [red].
g --> [green].
b --> [blue].
```